# regular expression from string

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to use regular expression to get some values from the String. Thing is, that it is quite complicated for me.

For example i have a string like this:

```
oneWord [first, second, third]
```

My output should be:

```
first
second
third
```

So i need words which are between [ and ]. Plus there can be a different number of words between [].

Tried using some regex creator, but that wasn't very accurate:

```
String re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re2="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
String re3=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re4="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; // Word 1
String re5=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re6="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; // Word 2
String re7=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re8="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; // Word 3
```

Comment: What's your expected output if the input is `oneWord [first, second, third] foo bar [foobar]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this, in just one line:

```
String[] words = str.replaceAll(".*\\[|\\].*", "").split(", ");
```

The first `replaceAll()` call strips off the leading and trailing wrapper, and the `split()` breaks up what's left into separate words.

Comment: @AvinashRaj no, but that is not the question. Note that with a small modification it could work

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below regex and get the words you want from group index 1.

```
(?:\[|(?<!^)\G),? *(\w+)(?=[^\[\]]*\])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nR7cC4/2)

Java regex would be,

```
(?:\\[|(?<!^)\\G),? *(\\w+)(?=[^\\[\\]]*\\])
```

**Example:**

```
String s = "oneWord [first, second, third] foo bar [foobar]";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?:\\[|(?<!^)\\G),? *(\\w+)(?=[^\\[\\]]*\\])");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
first
second
third
foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this string.

> String[] words = str.replaceAll(".*\[|\].*", "").split(", ");

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with method split.

```
String string = [first, second, third];
String[] parts = string.split(",");
String part1 = parts[0]; // first
String part2 = parts[1]; // second
String part3 = parts[2]; // third
```

if it dont work for you, please tell me that I will debug your regular expression.